# ListBox separate text in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, csv

I am using a ListBox control in a C# Windows form application, and I would like to divider/line in the listbox rows. I have not been able to find any information about this

[image]

this is my listbox that contain data of incoming call details

i need to separate this for save this data into database.

help me. refer some link to solve.

Comment: Well, it depends on what are you using to separate the "fields", but i guess you should be using [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: is it multicolumn listbox or what ?

Comment: it is normal listbox. when i make a phone call from 2011 to  2012. the call details are falls into that listbox like my question image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this; *split* line (by tabulation or space) into chunks, then *convert* each chunk into a field (of anonymous object):

```
var data = listBox1.Items
  .OfType<String>()
  .Select(line => line.Split(new Char[] {'\t', ' '},
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .Select(items => new {
     CallType = items[0],
     Source = items[1],
     Designation = items[2],
     At = DateTime.ParseExact(items[3], "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 
          TimeSpan.Parse(items[4]),
     Duration = TimeSpan.Parse(items[5]) 
   });
```

then loop:

```
foreach (var item in data) {
  if (item.CallType == "INCOMING") ...

  // date: item.At.Date; time: item.At.TimeOfDay
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where doy you get your data from? Does it give it to you as that string directly?

If so, and I understood right, you need to split a string into multiple (6 to be exact).

```
var splitet = $TheListBoxItemYouWantToGetInfo.ToString().Split(' ');
List<String> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string str in splitet)
{
    if (str != "") list.Add(str);
}
//Here you have all the data in "list" in separated strings, just cast/parse it if you need another type for the DB
```